# Is there a module to split payment methods

Tags: invoice, payment, payment-methods, create-invoice

I'm trying to see if a module or any code exists to allow a customer to pay with more than one method.  Or any other way to do this.

Ideally these cases would work:
Lets say they want to pay x on credit card A, and y on credit card B.
Lets say they want to pay x on credit card A, and y via Check.

Thanks!